# Настройка прав доступа

Tags: python, pycharm, django, postgresql, ubuntu

У меня есть проект на `Django`. Пытаюсь настроить `Pycharm 1.5.4`. Проблема в том, что `Pycharm` запускает процесс от имени пользователя, который запустил саму IDE, в следствии чего обращение к базе данных (`postgres`) идет от непонятного пользователя. База настроена так, что читать и писать туда может только пользователь `www-data`. Как разрешить проблему? Возможно ли выставить в `Pycharm` от имени кого запускать сервер? Или, правильней, добавить запись в настройку бд? ОС - Ubuntu 10.4.

Пробовал запускать так:

```
sudo -u www-data /bin/pycharm.sh
```

В этом случае pycharm падает.

Answer (score 1):

Всмысле, авторизация в БД идёт не по логину:паролю из settings.py? Ну напишите, тогда sh скрипт для запуска пайчарма через **su** с юзером **www-data** типа

```
su -l www-data -c "/home/user/PyCharm/bin/pycharm.sh"
```

Comment: Не катит. Pycharm'у нужен JDK. Если прописать все пути в pycharm.sh, то он падает сразу после запуска.

Comment: да нет. сделать стартовый файл типа start_charm.sh с содержанием типа:
`#!/bin/bash
su -l www-data -c "/path/to/pycharm.sh"`

который будет стартовать сам pycharm.sh под юзером www-data...

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Может падает потому, что у юзера www-data нет домашней папки?

Comment: Хз. Скорее прав доступа к чему либо не хватает.

Comment: ну чарм по-идее должен запускаться любым юзером, так что www-data тут не какой-то особенный, вариант с отсутсвием шелла в настрйоках юзера и домашней папки более вероятен. 

в целом проблема странная, настройка к БД должна происходить в settings.py юзером добавленным в postgre его родными командами... и под кем при этом запущен django или pycharm совершенно не важно... 

а тут какая-то экзотика прям :) можно узнать для чего так сделано? безопасность?

Comment: Все сделанно как у всех. Ошибка в том, что процес с базой крутится от имени root, а доступ запрашивает www-data. Если я запускаю сервер не из под IDE, то все ок.

Comment: не может такого быть! :) у меня сервер БД под юзером созданным для демона БД, runserver подо мной запускает и спокойно получает доступ к БД по логину:паролю из настроек. на боевом сервере gunicorn под www-data крутит джангу и получает доступ к БД запущенной под юзером созданным для демона БД. потому что "у всех" доступ к данным в СУБД происходит не под системным юзером, а под юзером созданным в самой СУБД которому, в самой СУБД, ему выданы определённые права на определённые БД и таблицы...